# Idea 1 of 3: Headhunter badge

Tags: feature-request, badge-request

Yesterday I brought a new user to Stack Overflow.

Just when I was about to privately answer yet another programming question I decided to do it.
She was kicking and screaming at first, but then she realized how cool Stack Overflow is and now we're both happy.

So, how about a badge that would reward bringing new members who will become active users (i.e. get 200 rep)? Name doesn't really matter.

Comment: Do we really want to encourage *more people* to join Stack Overflow? **I think not**.

Comment: 200 -> 10000 would make the suggestion better.

Comment: Sure we do. First of all SO is an ad-supported business, secondly — more people will hopefully produce better software.

Comment: How do you propose that the system would reliably identify who introduced the new user to SO and that the "new" user isn't really you in disguise?

Comment: When person is registering new account he should be able to find another user and point him as the one who brought him there. Require reputation for new users should prevent cheating.

Comment: I hate users. They're always putting bugs into my software!

Comment: I think a minimum amount of rep + a time limit would be better. Maybe something like 500 rep within 6 months.

Comment: @sneg -- for a person bent on getting the badge, getting 200 rep for a sock puppet wouldn't be hard.

Comment: 200 rep is just a first idea. The detailed requirements owners can figure out. How about the **main** idea itself?

Comment: @Jon Only 7% of registered users have 500 or more reputation... And that's counting everyone. Even 200 is pretty high. The vast majority (88%) has less than 200 rep points. And again, that's counting everyone. 10k is totally ludicrous, only 0.3% of users.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you could reliably detect that the person was introduced by another individual and the amount of rep the other person had to gain was substantial enough to discourage people from trying to do it with sock puppets -- say 1000 rep within a year -- then it would be ok.  One suggestion would be to be able to send an email with a coded invite to another individual's email address, assuming its not already registered.  The coded invite could be used to tie the new registration (assuming it happens) to the person who sent the invite.

Personally, this wouldn't change how I use and recommend SO, but I do see it as a positive behavior that SO might want to encourage with a badge.

Comment: To come up with a reasonable rep requirements for a new user I think it is needed to do a little statistical analysis of current users, like how soon on average people reach 1000 rep, how many are just mostly reader and so on.

Comment: But Jeff despises email :(

Comment: 1000 period is a ridiculously high number. 96% of all users have less than 1000 rep, that's counting everyone.

Comment: ok, but that 4% is still aroudn 10K users.  It's a moot point now, though with the new Announcer, Booster, and Publicist badges -- which are based on unique IPs from a shared link and not at all on rep.

Answer (score 8):

You have to be a bit careful when you encourage/reward people for referrals. People become overzealous and it leads to abuses/spam in other public forums. Sites that have affiliate/referral programs often have big problems with their name becoming associated with spam.

I know that badges don't have the same *value* as cash payments but, still, the potential is there for people to start spamming public forums to rack up the badges.

> > *"Join Stack Overflow. Tell them DaemonDOOdz327 sent you."*

Comment: Good point. Then maybe private invite through email is better.

Comment: That's why I'm suggesting an SO-generated email with an encoded invitation -- specific to both the email address specified and the user sending it. This could be rate-limited (as is everything else) to discourage it being used for such spam.  It could also verify that the person isn't already a member before being sent.

Answer (score 2):

**A "Real Job" Headhunter Badge**

How about a badge if you've hired somebody off of jobs or careers?

That's certainly something we should encourage!

(I originally was going to say "real headhunter" badge but "real" headhunting doesn't seem so great.)

Comment: I like this, but it's off-topic for this question. -1, but would upvote if it were a standalone feature request.

Answer (score 2):

Well, we don't have exactly this, but [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com) has some badges that are darn close.

[image]

We do have: Announcer, Booster, Publicist.

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/announcer-booster-and-publicist-badges/