# Idea 2 of 3: Promoter badge

Tags: feature-request, badge-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Idea 1 of 3: Headhunter badge.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42071/idea-1-of-3-headhunter-badge)

Every now and then I post a link to SO on some local board when people ask a programming question. I'm always wondering if someone followed it and became a permanent user.

It would be good if I could make that link a unique one, so that SO could trace it and maybe reward me with a badge?

Comment: This could be done with the blog badge I would think reasonably easily.

Comment: Do we have already some kind of blog badge?

Comment: I think @tvan's referring to Flair?

Comment: Oh, I see. Well, yes, at least like that. Maybe I'll start blogging. :)

Comment: @user -- yep, flair, blog badge, whatever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I vaguely suspect something like this would result in a lot of people spamming links to the trilogy in places where it isn't really appropriate in order to get this badge.

Comment: If it brings people to SO etc. is that a bad thing inherently?  Given the spam is elsewhere I mean?